# Grid items overflow container with max width

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I've a css grid and multiple items inside it. Right know it's covering the whole width possible. What I want is to limit the width of the container (such as making it only 700px) instead of covering the whole width.

I've tried to use width or max-width properties for the container but none of them is successful. The content inside the container overflows. I should be missing something but do not know what.

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/sercanyilmaz/full/YaRmPN/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(350, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(33, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  background-color: #a5adb0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Muli';
}

.func {
  grid-column: span 25;
  grid-row: span 3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #20252A;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num {
  grid-column: span 24;
  grid-row: span 6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #20252A;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back {
  grid-column: span 38;
}

.letters {
  grid-column: span 24;
  grid-row: span 6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #20252A;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab {
  grid-column: span 38;
}

.caps {
  grid-column: span 42;
}

.enter {
  grid-column: span 44;
}

.left-shift {
  grid-column: span 50;
}

.right-shift {
  grid-column: span 60;
}

.fn {
  grid-column: span 22;
}

.left-command,
.right-command {
  grid-column: span 28;
}

.space {
  grid-column: span 120;
}

.up {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.down {
  grid-row: span 3;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  ;
}

.left,
.right {
  grid-column: span 28;
}

.func:active,
.num:active,
.letters:active {
  border-bottom: 5px inset #20252A;
  background: #111;
}

.down:active {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
  border-top: 5px inset #20252A;
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- first row -->

  <div class="func">esc</div>
  <div class="func">F1</div>
  <div class="func">F2</div>
  <div class="func">F3</div>
  <div class="func">F4</div>
  <div class="func">F5</div>
  <div class="func">F6</div>
  <div class="func">F7</div>
  <div class="func">F8</div>
  <div class="func">F9</div>
  <div class="func">F10</div>
  <div class="func">F11</div>
  <div class="func">F12</div>
  <div class="func">F13</div>

  <!-- second row -->

  <div class="num">~<br/>`</div>
  <div class="num">!<br/>1</div>
  <div class="num">@<br/>2</div>
  <div class="num">#<br/>3</div>
  <div class="num">$<br/>4</div>
  <div class="num">%<br/>5</div>
  <div class="num">^<br/>6</div>
  <div class="num">&<br/>7</div>
  <div class="num">*<br/>8</div>
  <div class="num">(<br/>9</div>
  <div class="num">)<br/>0</div>
  <div class="num">-<br/>_</div>
  <div class="num">+<br/>=</div>
  <div class="num back">delete</div>

  <!-- third row -->

  <div class="letters tab"><i class="material-icons">&#xe31c;</i></div>
  <div class="letters">Q</div>
  <div class="letters">W</div>
  <div class="letters">E</div>
  <div class="letters">R</div>
  <div class="letters">T</div>
  <div class="letters">Y</div>
  <div class="letters">U</div>
  <div class="letters">I</div>
  <div class="letters">O</div>
  <div class="letters">P</div>
  <div class="letters">{<br/>[</div>
  <div class="letters">}<br/>]</div>
  <div class="letters">|<br/>/</div>

  <!-- fourth row -->

  <div class="letters caps">caps lock</div>
  <div class="letters">A</div>
  <div class="letters">S</div>
  <div class="letters">D</div>
  <div class="letters">F</div>
  <div class="letters">G</div>
  <div class="letters">H</div>
  <div class="letters">J</div>
  <div class="letters">K</div>
  <div class="letters">L</div>
  <div class="letters">:<br/>;</div>
  <div class="letters">"<br/>'</div>
  <div class="letters enter">enter<br/>return</div>

  <!-- fifth row -->

  <div class="letters left-shift">shift</div>
  <div class="letters">Z</div>
  <div class="letters">X</div>
  <div class="letters">C</div>
  <div class="letters">V</div>
  <div class="letters">B</div>
  <div class="letters">N</div>
  <div class="letters">M</div>
  <div class="letters">
    <<br/>,</div>
  <div class="letters">><br/>.</div>
  <div class="letters">?<br/>\</div>
  <div class="letters right-shift">shift</div>

  <!-- sixth row -->

  <div class="letters fn">fn</div>
  <div class="letters">control</div>
  <div class="letters">option</div>
  <div class="letters left-command">⌘<br/>command</div>
  <div class="letters space"></div>
  <div class="letters right-command">⌘<br/>command</div>
  <div class="letters">option</div>
  <div class="letters left">&larr;</div>
  <div class="letters up">&uarr;</div>
  <div class="letters right">&rarr;</div>
  <div class="letters down">&darr;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use max-width:700px; the contents overlaps in the container, they are not responsive. you can add overflow:scroll but its not good, i think you should use % in the width of each keyboard key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `grid-column-gap` you have set on the grid container.

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(350, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(33, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 4px; <----- PROBLEM HERE
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    background-color: #a5adb0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: 'Muli';
}
```

When you set `grid-gap: 4px`, that is shorthand for:

- `grid-row-gap: 4px`
- `grid-column-gap: 4px`

(Incidentally, the `grid-row-gap` set in the shorthand is overridden with your next line of code.)

Now look at how many columns you have set:

- `grid-template-columns: repeat(350, 1fr)`

Now multiply 350 * 4px. **The minimum possible width of a grid row is 1400px**.

For an illustration, set the container's width to 1400px and remove the `padding: 15px`. The grid items begin to overflow at 1399px.

If you disable `grid-gap: 4px` you'll see that your layout scales nicely without any overflow.

Depending on how you want to space the keys, you'll have to test different units on the column gaps, such as straight percentages (`%`) or viewport percentages (`vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, `vmax`, etc).
Or consider using less (wider) columns.